# Create text file, tar the file and put it into an inputstream?

Tags: java, inputstream, tar, fileoutputstream

I want to put a textfile containing just one string into a tar archive and put this tar file into an inputstream... I want to do this "on the fly", without saving any temporary files to the disk...

I tried out this snippet, where I end up with a file:

```
FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream ("helloworld.txt");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } 

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    String config = "HelloWorld!";
    byte[] b = config.getBytes();
    try {
        baos.write(b);
        baos.writeTo(fos);
        fos.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And I had a look at the jtar library:
https://code.google.com/p/jtar/

So I would like to put that textfile directly into that tar, but I also don't need that   new FileOutputStream( "c:/test/test.tar" ), instead I want to put it into an inputstream directly.

I'm a bit confused with all those inputstreams/outputstreams and I'm not sure if it's even possible to move around a bunch of those streams instead of creating temporary files to do this.

THX & BR

Comment: what does the inputstream represent ? is it a process input ?

Comment: I'm sendig (HTTP PUT) it to a REST API which takes it in and expects a tar stream.

Answer (score 1):

Just get rid of the `FileOutputStream` and the `bos.writeTo()`, and do:

```
ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream (baos.toByteArray());
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the best way to do it, but this seems to work, but not exactly as I imagined:

```
        File tempFile = File.createTempFile("config", ".properties");

    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile));
    bw.write("Helloworld!!!!");
    bw.close();

    File tempTarFile = File.createTempFile("config", ".tar");

    FileOutputStream dest = new FileOutputStream( tempTarFile );
    TarOutputStream out = new TarOutputStream( new BufferedOutputStream( dest ) );
    out.putNextEntry(new TarEntry(tempFile, "config.properties"));
    BufferedInputStream origin = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream( tempFile ));

    int count;
    byte data[] = new byte[2048];
    while((count = origin.read(data)) != -1) {
       out.write(data, 0, count);
    }
    out.flush();
    origin.close();
    out.close();

    tempFile.delete();
    tempTarFile.delete();

    InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(tempTarFile);

//to check if it worked:

//      OutputStream outputStream = null;
//
//      try {
//
//          // write the inputStream to a FileOutputStream
//          outputStream = 
//                        new FileOutputStream(new File("config.tar"));
//
//          int read = 0;
//          byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
//
//          while ((read = inputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
//              outputStream.write(bytes, 0, read);
//          }
//
//          System.out.println("Done!");
//
//      } catch (IOException e) {
//          e.printStackTrace();
//      } finally {
//          if (inputStream != null) {
//              try {
//                  inputStream.close();
//              } catch (IOException e) {
//                  e.printStackTrace();
//              }
//          }
//          if (outputStream != null) {
//              try {
//                  // outputStream.flush();
//                  outputStream.close();
//              } catch (IOException e) {
//                  e.printStackTrace();
//              }
//
//          }
//      }
```